# Primefaces components doesn't work in websphere 8.5

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, websphere, ibm-rad

i am using **IBM RAD 8.5.1** to create a JSF 2 project and run it on **websphere 8.5**

i used the **File > New > Web Project Wizard**
,and i added the JSF & Primefaces as follows:

**Java Build Path > Add External Jars**

- **jsf-api-2.1.7.jar (com.sun.faces)**
- **jsf-impl-2.1.7.jar (com.sun.faces)**
- **primefaces-3.3.1.jar**

**Project Facets** are:

- **Dynamic Web Module 3**
- **Java 1.6**
- **JavaScript 1**
- **JavaServer Faces 2**
- **JSTL 1.1**
- **WebSphere Web (Co-existence) 8.5**
- **WebSphere Web (Extended) 8.5**

**xhtml** page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ice="http://www.icesoft.com/icefaces/component"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" 
    xmlns:pretty="http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces" 
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">    
<h:head>
    <title> Welcome </title>
</h:head>


 <h:body>

   <p:layout fullPage="true">

    <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" header="Top" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
        <h:outputText value="North unit content." />
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" header="Bottom" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
        <h:outputText value="South unit content." />
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="200" header="Left" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
        <h:outputText value="West unit content." />
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="200" header="Right" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true" effect="drop">
        <h:outputText value="Right unit content." />
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
        <h:form>
            This fullPage layout consists of five different layoutUnits which are resizable and closable by default.

        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>

 </p:layout>

 </h:body>        

</html>
```

- **web.xml**:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

      <display-name>vip</display-name>
      <servlet>
          <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
          <enabled>true</enabled>
          <async-supported>false</async-supported>
      </servlet>

      <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>
          /faces/*</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>

      <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>
       pages/hello.xhtml
       </welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>


  </web-app>
  ```

when running the project on IE 9, the primefaces component is not rendered and i only get the text of the center **layoutUnit**

please advise how to fix this, thanks.

Comment: Is this a websphere or IE9 problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your Primefaces jar should be in Web App Library in build path. The easiest way to do it just copy and paste your primeface jar file to /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib in your web project. After implementing do check in your editor/IDE, while typing p: if you see p:{all tags} than it is implemented correctly